How do I solve Error: Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info
I'm hit with this error:

Error: Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info.

I tried to test with firebase login --reauth
But it didn't work
Has anyone run into this/have a solution for it?
Please help me if you know any solution.

Did you do as the error message says and "See firebase-debug.log for more info"?  What does it say?  Please edit the question with all the details you have available.
